# nginx location always equals index.php

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm running a nginx server behind a traefik LB on a kubernetes cluster. When a request comes in on nginx the location and uri are always /index.php but the request_uri does show the correct path. The access log also shows the correct path.

Because of this I can not use the location blocks inside the config. The current config really is a basic out of the box one and I do not set of redirect anywhere. I did setup the behind loadbalancer part (really wide to be sure):

```
    set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
```

Anyone ever experienced the same or got any suggestions?

I've tried to minimize the config to just do the bear minimum but the problem still exist. I also do not see any strange force to index stuff on the loadbalancer part.